# VBA: Html response to DOMDocument

Tags: vba, dom, xpath

I'm trying to automaticly parse a website (eg. http://www.delhaizedirect.be/nl/Search/Duvel and get the price of the first item in the list in VBA. Therefore, I'm getting the HTML, which works fine. But when I parse the HTML into a DOMDocument and apply an XPath query, I don't get any result.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Public Function zoekDelhaizePrijs(Artikel As String)

Dim URL As String
URL = "http://www.delhaizedirect.be/nl/Search/" + Artikel

Dim website As Object
Set website = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

Call website.Open("GET", URL, False)
Call website.Send("")

Dim XPathQuery As String
XPathQuery = "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/div[1]/div/div[2]/p[1]"

Dim dom As DOMDocument60
Set dom = New DOMDocument60
dom.async = False

dom.validateOnParse = False

'Debug.Print website.responseText

dom.LoadXML website.responseText
dom.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

Dim node As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set node = dom.SelectNodes(XPathQuery)

Dim title As IXMLDOMNode

For Each title In node
    Debug.Print title.Text
Next

End Function
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the DOCTYPE at the top of the page declaring it as "XHTML 1.0 Transitional", the page returned for the "Duvel" query isn't even well-formed XML. Therefore, it fails to parse into the DOMDocument60 object and thus no nodes are returned. Even though you have set `validateOnParse=False`, this doesn't remove the requirement for the document to be well-formed XML.

You could load the response from the website into a string then manually correct it into well-formed XML before loading it into the DOMDocument60. This could take some time as you need to fix a problem, run your function and then examine the attributes of `dom.parseError` to find the next problem.

The problems with the XHTML document include:

- `&` characters not replaced by `&amp;` entities - e.g. `value="/nl/Search/Duvel?NB_REPLY=20&brand=Delhaize&page=1"` instead of `value="/nl/Search/Duvel?NB_REPLY=20&amp;brand=Delhaize&amp;page=1"`
- attributes with no values - e.g. `<option selected value="/nl/Search/Duvel?NB_REPLY=20&page=1">` instead of `<option selected="selected" value="/nl/Search/Duvel?NB_REPLY=20&page=1">`
- tags not closed - e.g. `<div><p></p><p></p><p><span><span></span></span></div>` (there's a missing `</p>`)

There are some specific MSXML2 issues as well. DTDs are prohibited by default in DOMDocument60 so you would need `dom.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False` before you try and load the XML.

Your XPath query may also fall foul of MSXML2's problem with default namespaces - see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313372) (that link refers to MXSML 4.0 but the problem still exists in MSXML 6.0). As the page has a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, you need to:

- declare a namespace prefix corresponding to that namespace `dom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:r='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'"` and
- use that in your XPath query `XPathQuery = "/r:html/r:body/r:div[1]/r:div[3]/r:div[1]/r:div[1]/r:div[3]/r:ul/r:div[1]/r:div/r:div[2]/r:p[1]"`

Alternatively you could try to load the response from the website into an HTMLDocument instead and use methods like `getElementsByClassName` to locate the desired data. There's no requirement for the document to be well-formed XML in this case

These are the replacements I needed to make to get the Duvel page to work. Other pages on that site may need a different set of replacements. I wouldn't claim that this is anything like best practice but it works for this one specific page. The standard entities (plus `&nbsp;`) are temporarily renamed to allow the incorrect `&` characters in the document to be replaced. `&nbsp;` is replaced by the numeric equivalent:

```
Dim webResponse As String
webResponse = website.responseText
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&nbsp;", "^nbsp;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&amp;", "^amp;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&lt;", "^lt;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&gt;", "^gt;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&quot;", "^quot;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&apos;", "^apos;")

webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "&", "&amp;")

webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "^nbsp;", "&#160;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "^amp;", "&amp;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "^lt;", "&lt;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "^gt;", "&gt;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "^quot;", "&quot;")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "^apos;", "&apos;")

webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "<option selected ", "<option selected=" & Chr$(34) & "selected" & Chr$(34) & " ")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, " style=>", " style=" & Chr$(34) & Chr$(34) & ">")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "]]&gt;", "]]>")
webResponse = Replace(webResponse, "<span>prijs</span></span>", "<span>prijs</span></span></p>")
```

Comment: Thank you for this very elaborate answer!

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
//div[@class="displayProdList"][1]//p[@class="prodListPrice"]
```

Comment: Did you test it with the same VBA code? It indeed works if I use an XPath plugin to test the query, but it doesn't work with the code.